# How to implement sub function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I implement sub functions in JavaScript

```
callMethod(); // Works
callMethod.doThisWay(); // Still works
```

Comment: Well what did you try? Since functions can have properties attached to them, the trivial approach should work.

Comment: Side note: a sub function is called a "(static) method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can :-)

Just write

```
const callMethod = function () {
  // ...
};

callMethod.doThisWay = function () {
  // ...
};
```

and you're done :-)

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
var callMethod = function() {
  this.doThisWay = function () {
    alert('doThisWay'); 
  }

    alert('callMethod');

  return this;
};

var a = new callMethod();
a.doThisWay();
```

there is some other ways to do this also.